# Get either the_content or the_excerpt depending upon custom page type

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I've create a category template called 'category-blog.php', designed to show all the excerpts of my blog entries. However one custom post type (quote) relies on displaying the content, not the excerpt, so I need to create a simple 'if' argument to say 'if this is a standard post, display only the excerpt, but if this is a quote post, display the content. I am assuming I have to do something with (get_template_part) but I am unsure what. All this happens within the loop.

```
<div class="entry-content">
<php if custom page type is 'quote', then...
<?php the_content(); ?>
<else...
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function **get_post_type()**

```
<div class="entry-content">
<?php
if(get_post_type() == 'quote'){
   the_content();
}else{
   //something else
}
?>
</div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

Comment: I'm not sure that works in my case. If I use this: `<?php
                        if(get_post_type() == 'quote'){
                           the_content();
                        }else{
                           the_excerpt();
                        }
                        ?>`... it still shows the excerpt for the quote custom page.

Comment: Is your custom post type named `quote`?

Comment: Yes. I'm using a child of twentythirteen theme which has different post formats, one of which is called 'quote'. It uses the page template 'content-quote.php'. In the post edit area of WP it has a list of formats, one of which is 'Quote'.